# Interpret 0x string as hex in Python

Tags: python, types, casting

I'm appending some hex bytes into a `packet = []` and I want to return these hex bytes in the form of `0x__` as hex data.

```
packet.append("2a")
packet.append("19")
packet.append("00")
packet.append("00")

packHex = []

for i in packet:
    packHex.append("0x"+i) #this is wrong

return packHex
```

How do I go about converting `('2a', '19', '00', '00')` in `packet` to get `(0x2a, 0x19, 0x0, 0x0)` in `packHex`? I need real hex data, not strings that look like hex data.

I'm assembling a packet to be sent over `pcap`, `pcap_sendpacket(fp,packet,len(data))` where `packet` should be a hexadecimal list or tuple for me, maybe it can be done in decimal, haven't tried, I prefer hex. Thank you for your answer.

`packetPcap[:len(data)] = packHex`

**Solved:**

`for i in packet: packHex.append(int(i,16))`

If output in hex needed, this command can be used:
`print ",".join(map(hex, packHex))`

Comment: Sorry, tryna' keep it "real"... - hip 1 min ago

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just build a `list` of `int`s and just print them out in base 16 (either by using `"%x"%value` or `hex`) instead? If the values are given to you in this form (e.g. from some other source), you can use `int` with the optional second parameter to turn this into an `int`.

```
>>> int('0x'+'2a',16)
42
>>> packet=["2a","19","00","00"]
>>> packet=[int(p,16) for p in packet]
>>> packet
[42, 25, 0, 0]
>>> print ", ".join(map(hex,packet))
0x2a, 0x19, 0x0, 0x0
```

Comment: I'm assembling a packet to be sent over `pcap`, `pcap_sendpacket(fp,packet,len(data))` where `packet` should be a hexadecimal list or tuple for me, maybe it can be done in decimal, haven't tried, I prefer hex. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Soulseekah: All values are binary under the hood. Hex or decimal is only the representation when you convert it to a string when printing. So, distinctions like "hex number" and "decimal number" are meaningless for values stored in variables.

Comment: I need `packetPcap[:len(data)] = packHex` where `packHex` contains something like `(0x00, 0x1F, 0x3C, 0x84, 0x70, 0x22, 0x1C, 0xAF, 0xF7)`. Thank you for your help. +1

Comment: `map(hex,packet)` is interesting. So basically it doesn't matter whether the list/tuple contains hex or dec, it's all just bits in the end. I can supply `(0x00, 39, 29, 0x32)` and everything is going to be parsed into decimals. I can then use `map(hex,` to visually get hex for better reading. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @Soulseekah: Yes. Except, everything gets parsed into *binary* not decimals. The default base that Python expects in literals is decimal, but even that is converted to binary once it is read.

Answer (score 5):

You don't really want 'hex data', you want integers. Hexadecimal notation only makes sense when you have numbers represented as strings.

To solve your problem use a list comprehension:

```
[int(x, 16) for x in packet]
```

Or to get the result as a tuple:

```
tuple(int(x, 16) for x in packet)
```

Comment: Nope, that does not result in hex values, that results in decimal values.

Comment: That's just the representation. Integers are numbers. Hexadecimal and decimal and octal are ways of representing the number. `0x34` and `52` are *the same number*. If you want to *print* the number in hexadecimal, that's a different matter altogether, and that's where the 'x' string format comes along.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and coments. The matter has been cleared now. Sorry for not accepting your answer @Mark, I liked the extra `map` thrown in by @MAK, otherwise you were the first and to the point. Thanks.

Comment: There's also the `hex()` built-in for converting a number to a hexadecimal string representation, including leading `0x`.